# Remove spaces between two rectangles in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make something similar to the mail app. I want to remove the spaces between all the rectangles. How do i do that?[image: This this the code that i wrote and you can see the spaces between the rectangles, which i want to remove]

I have tried using fixedSize() function but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please note it is always preferred to post actual code instead of screenshots of code.

Comment: Wrap `ForEach` with `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` has an implicit `VStack` of sorts but you can't control its spacing afaik.

Try wrapping your content inside a `VStack(spacing: 0)`.

You'll probably want to then add some padding after your `ZStack`.

You also shouldn't need to specify the width with `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`. If it isn't filling the available space you could use `maxWidth: .infinity`.